# Error in Flutter .DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, flutter, dart, androidx

this is an Issuse

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives

When i Add Finger Local Auth

```
  local_auth: ^0.4.0+1
```

with api in gradle

Answer (score 0):

This Error is with AndroidX just be carful to Delete it 
from gradle and Change local auth from

`local_auth: ^0.4.0+1`

To

`local_auth: ^0.3.0`